# How does tBu2Si(OTf)2 react in uridine in DMF at 0°C

Tags: organic-chemistry

I have to write the mechanism of a four steps reaction that aims to transform uridine into a deoxythymidine by following these steps :

1. (tBu)2Si(OTf)2, DMF, 0°C
2. ClCSOPh, DMAP, 20°C
3. AIBN, Bu3SnH, 80°C, toluen
4. TBAF, THF

I am stuck in the first step. I know that DMF promotes a SN2, I found that the Si atom is electrophilic but in the uridine, I couldn't find the most nucleophilic atom that can react in Si. Could you please help me to find it?

[image]

here is the reaction I wrote after the explanation : [image]

Comment: Think about the process here. The object of the sequence is to remove one of the oxygens of the N-heterocycle so you do not want the oxygens on the sugar reacting with the ClCSOPh and the last step (TBAF) removes silyl protecting groups.

Comment: @Waylander thank you for your reply I want to show you what I did in order to be sure that I got all what you said

Comment: Looks correct to me